# Firefox CSS not loading

Tags: css, firefox

I stumbled across an odd issue in firefox today.

The stylesheet for one of my pages doesn't load in Firefox, although it does on Chrome and Safari. When I open Firefox Developer, I can see this stylesheet. If I open it up in the Style Editor section and make any change (e.g. hit space one time somewhere on the sheet), the css is applied to the page.

Since the stylesheet seems to be loaded up properly after all, anyone know why it's not showing up initially? Probably an obvious solution, but I've been stumped on this for a while. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post your `<link rel="stylesheet".. `

Comment: if you open the webpage source code in the `browser->view source` and you click on the link to the CSS stylesheet in the header, does that link take you to the source code for a error 404 page?

Comment: Also check if you have any javascript and if the javascript loads correctly, and if the javascript loads *before* the CSS , also if you have other error-prone CSS pages that load *before* the sheet then it will not load, as CSS takes up the entire loading span and does not load asyncronously.

Comment: thanks everyone! jad, my link looks like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystylesheet.css"></link>`. martin, i tried that, and it brings me to a page with this message: "the image [url/to/stylesheet] cannot be displayed because it contains errors." the stylesheet is linked first thing in the head section of the page, and there is nothing before it.

Answer (score 3):

Do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on PC or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on Mac. I struggled with this for hours until I found this.

Comment: You can't really expect your users to have to do this though.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your comment, the problem is that the stylesheet is being processed as an image.
If you open your firefox console you should probably see a warning.
So what happened is that when you edited it using the StyleEditor, the correct mime type is being fixed.

If your stylesheet is generated from a backend, you need to make sure to set the correct mimetype in the headers.
If that does't solve it, try to "save as" your file and make sure it's being saved with an encoding of UTF-8 and using an IDE or a coding text editor

Comment: thanks jad! yeah it says the mimetype of the css file is image/jpg, but i can't figure out how to fix it. i'm using sass, which should output automatically in utf-8, and i explicitly declared it too just in case with @charset 'UTF-8';. i also put in type as "text/css", so i'm not sure what to do...

Comment: Are you using any build tool?

Comment: Oke i have I ask a few questions. Are you behind Apache?

Comment: yeah, it's an apache server

Comment: Try adding this to your .htaccess: `AddType text/css .css`

Comment: hmm... same issue remains

Comment: i've stuffed everything into an internal stylesheet for now. thanks again for all the help, will look into this when i have more time